# How to log to log console in Jupyterlab?

Tags: logging, jupyter-lab

I have imported basic `logging` module in Jupyterlab notebook. There's a log console which shows errors and warnings. I want to print also debug messages in that console. How can I do it? I think that it has something to do with adding appropriate handler, but I don't know how.

Comment: This question was also asked on: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-work-with-log-console/11548/